# How to implement Save in an in-memory repository

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have the following code

```
foreach (var obj in MyList)
{
  // BL
  repository.Add(obj)
   // BL
  repository.Update(obj)
}
```

I have two classes that implement IRepository. One class uses MsSql and one in-memory.
the in-memory implementation uses List to store my data.
If I use the MsSql class then all the data is already stored in DB.
If I use the in-memory then I need to insert all the data from the repository's list to DB after the foreach loop.
I'm not sure what is the best way to do this OOP wise.

I can add a Save method to IRepository but that means that the MsSql class will implement a method that it doesn't need.
Another option is to add a method only in the in-memory class and to do something like this:

```
IRepository rep = repository as InMemoryRepository
if (rep != null)
{
    rep.Save()
}
```

what do you think?

Comment: "If I use the in-memory then I need to insert all the data from the list to DB" - I don't get this part.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Because the data is stored in memory and not in the database it needs to be saved manually to the DB afterwards.

Comment: Why the inmemory provider would need to insert the data into the db?

Comment: @WiktorZychla I don't know, I made this up by reading the question. Not sure if it's true what he says.

Comment: @Measuring is correct.
WiktorZychlait, it needs to be saved because that data needs to be persistent

Comment: Well "in memory" is really the opposite of persistent, if you need to persist the data you should sync it to a file when data is added or removed (you can still keep it in memory if you want for performance reasons though).

Comment: What about having Add(T) and Add(IEnumerable<T>) in IRepository? At least you wouldn't have to commit changes on every added object.

Answer (score 0):

You should have methods common to all Repository implementations (MSSQL, In-Memory) in the base Interface.

SaveToDatabase is a very in-memory specific method and should be part of the InMemory repository implementation class. Do not make it part of the base interface since it may not have any meaning for other concrete implementations.

The other option is to implement the persist method of the in-memory repository such that it saves it in the list as well as saves it in the DB. (though it is mixing of concerns)

```
public interface IRepository
{
 void Add(MyType object);
}

public class SqlRepository : IRepository
{
 public void Add(MyType object)
 {
  // saves to DB
 }
} 

public class InMemoryRepository : IRepository
{
 List<MyType> store = new List<MyType>();

 public void Add(MyType object)
 {
  // saves to list store.
  // may also, additionally store to DB.
  IRepository dbRep = DependencyInjection.GiveMeDatabaseRepository<IRepository>();

  // null check so that if tomorrow, there is no SQL repository, this code doesn't break.
  if (dbRep != null )
  {
   dbRep.Add(object);
  }
 }

 // this is another explicit option
 public void AddToDatabase(MyType object)
 {
   IRepository dbRep = DependencyInjection.GiveMeDatabaseRepository<IRepository>();
   dbRep.Add(object);
 }
}
```

Comment: thats fine.. you dont need to add 1 object at a time.. the AddToDatabase could **NOT** take a parameter and just save all items in store object into the DB in 1 shot.. the point of the answer being that, the save to db is a very specific behavior of list repository and should not be in the interface'

Comment: i'm inclined to agree